# How to build package with uclibc with bitbake - Bitbake raises MultipleMatches exception while trying to build uclibc

Tags: linux, uclibc, angstrom-linux, openembedded

I am trying to build `uclibc` for `arm7a` architecture, via bitbake, but I get the following output

```
user@ubuntu:~/stuff$ bitbake -b uclibc
ERROR: Unable to match uclibc (19 matches found):
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_git.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.30.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.30.2.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/bfin-uclibc_svn.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.31.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_0.9.30.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.29.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_0.9.30.2.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_0.9.31.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_0.9.29.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_git.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.28.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.30.1.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_0.9.30.3.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_0.9.28.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc++/uclibc++_git.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/elf2flt_svn.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc-initial_0.9.30.1.bb
ERROR:     /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.30.3.bb
ERROR: Command execution failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 102, in runAsyncCommand
    commandmethod(self.cmds_async, self, options)
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 190, in buildFile
    command.cooker.buildFile(bfile, task)
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 608, in buildFile
    buildfile = self.matchFile(fn)
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 591, in matchFile
    raise MultipleMatches
MultipleMatches
```

I am trying also to build a specific recipe (Am I doing it wrong?) but I get

```
user@ubuntu:~/stuff$ bitbake -b /home/user/stuff/openembedded/recipes/uclibc/uclibc_0.9.31.bb 
ERROR: Command execution failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 102, in runAsyncCommand
    commandmethod(self.cmds_async, self, options)
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/command.py", line 190, in buildFile
    command.cooker.buildFile(bfile, task)
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/cooker.py", line 618, in buildFile
    self.status.add_from_recipeinfo(vfn, info)
  File "/home/user/stuff/bitbake/lib/bb/cache.py", line 583, in add_from_recipeinfo
    for provide in info.provides:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my own question because of the lack of informations I've found searching for this argument. I hope it is not inappropriate. So..

First of all, `bitbake` should be called without `-b` option in order to calculate package dependencies

```
bitbake package
```

Then, there's no need to build `uclibc` directly because bitbake builds it automatically when necessary (for that you have to use `bitbake` without `-b` option). At this point it is not finished, because for my version of Angstrom distribution (2010.x) uclibc is not default library built by bitbake but eglibc is built. So you have to add to your `stuff/build/conf/local.conf` this line: `ANGSTROMLIBC = "uclibc"`, found at [this faq](http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Uclibc_FAQ)

In the end you can find all ipk packages and sources at your `stuff/tmp/deploy/uclibc`.